# Amazon LEX Facebook Integration: Access User Profile and Location Data?

Tags: aws-lambda, bots, facebook-messenger, amazon-lex

Does any one know if AWS LEX when integrated into Facebook Messenger can Access the Facebook Users Profile Information and or Location Information. Want to make my chat bot location aware and personalised to the individual using it.

I need to send the user id in order to personalized some options in future conversations, using lambda witn nodejs
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize the amazon lex send the user id and the token from my page, so we can call the facebook api with that information